# What is the best online English translation of Tanach?

Tags: tanach, technology, translation

I am aware of a number of partial or [complete](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm) English [translations](http://mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0.htm) of Tana"ch online, but I am wondering if there are any I am unaware of, especially that fulfill the following criteria:

1. Precision of translation (the more the better)
2. Copyability (no tables, strange HTML formatting, etc.)
3. Freedom ([as in beer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/free_as_in_beer))

Comment: I used the technology tag because #2 is at least as important as #1.

Comment: [Rabbi Kaplan's translation of the _chamisha chumshe Tora_ is online.](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp) I'm not posting this as an answer, however, as it fails criterion 1 terribly: The translation is _great_, but not precise (assuming you mean "literal") at all.

Comment: @msh210 Right, it fails on that one, but it is good to see that that resource exists anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the two best websites for getting english translations are not Jewish in origin.

http://bible.cc/genesis/1-1.htm

and

http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+1%3A1&version=YLT;NIV;NASB

But it is hard to deny that they fit all of your criteria.

Biblegateway might win because of its search features and multple layouts which you can get results, and you can see large sections of text at a time if you wish such as this:  http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+1&version=YLT

In general, in biblegatway, "Young's Literal translation" will most likely match the Jewish translation better than the others.

Breslov.com also has the JPS translation, which is supposed to be fairly accurate.  But it's navigation is a bit lacking.  http://www.breslov.com/bible/

Comment: Re Young's Literal Translation - There is a telling passage on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_Literal_Translation) devoted thereto: "If a translation gives a present tense when the original gives a past, or a past when it has a present... it is clear that verbal inspiration is as much overlooked as if it had no existence." This, and oddities like translating the first instance of ברא as "preparation" give me pause. But he did write [a concordance](http://goo.gl/IqkiE), so who am I to judge?

Comment: All translations are bad, Young just seems the least Christian.

Answer (score 1):

[Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm) has great translation  with Rashi commentaries. It's the best you can find online.

Comment: A relevant link would greatly enhance this answer, as chabad.org is a huge site.

Comment: http://m.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16007/jewish/Chapter-10.htm#v=4&showrashi=true

Comment: Unfortunately, without even scrutinizing the translation, the version linked fails on criterion #2. In between each verse there are HTML formatting elements, containers for translation and commentary, etc. This makes it very hard to copy more than a verse at a time. I guess I didn't know about Sefaria 4 years ago. . .

Comment: This is linked in the question.

Comment: @WAF Sefaria didn't exist 4 years ago, I think.