# best Hebrew-English Tanakh in printed form, interlinear if possible?

Tags: product-recommendation, hebrew, tanach, language

I've been using the Artscroll Interlinear series to read the Torah and it's helping me make a lot of progress in finally learning Tanakh Hebrew. But outside of the five scrolls and the psalms, Artscroll does not provide an interlinear translation for the rest of the books of the Tanakh, and I could not find any other Jewish sources for a printed interlinear publication.

What is available is an interlinear "old testament" from a Christian publisher using the ESV (English Standard Version) translation. From the online sample I've seen, the translation is very literal in a way that will aid in my language learning, and also from what I've seen so far, avoids overly Christianizing the text. In fact, the translation in many ways seems more literal and useful than the Artscroll, which sometimes paraphrases words and expressions.

With all that, I'm still hesitant to order the ESV interlinear because it somehow seems creepy to me as a Jewish person to be using a Christian-produced Tanakh to learn Hebrew. Am I just being narrow-minded and bigoted and missing the point of learning Tanakh in the first place? I'm not used to thinking of myself as some kind of narrow-minded xenophobe, but who knows?

Does anybody else have experience with this particular interlinear translation ([https://www.amazon.com/Hebrew-English-Interlinear-ESV-Testament-Stuttgartensia/dp/1433501139](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1433501139)), and any advice on whether it would be an acceptable volume for a Jewish reader? Any suggestions on other interlinear or at least dual language (Hebrew-English) translations that would be helpful? I have the Artscroll dual language Yehoshua, but the English and Hebrew often do not line up on the same part of the page and sometimes not even on the same page at all, so it's less useful to me at this point than I was hoping. Thanks for any help!
​

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/what-is-the-best-english-translation-of-the-tanakh-hard-copy-not-online

Comment: I do have experience with this particular Bible. I would not invest the money to purchase it. It clearly has a Christian bias when translating. It's not nearly like the ArtScroll Interlinear Chumashim. The format is confusing, the print looks like it's been photocopied, and the text is extremely small.

Comment: No matter how subtle the errors, the translations of other religions will give you the wrong context and lead to mistakes in pushing their agenda. A good translation (such as the Hirsch Chumash) will be better even though it is not interlinear.

Answer (score 2):

The [New Jewish Publication Society of America Tanakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Jewish_Publication_Society_of_America_Tanakh) (NJPS) in my opinion is the best out there.  Try going to [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Tanakh?lang=bi) to look for yourself.

Comment: Is NJPS available in interlinear form?

Comment: Yes. I have one I am looking at right now in front of me.

Comment: Best in a comparative sense. If you like Artscroll's style, NJPS is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider The Living Torah and The Living Nach. Here’s a [link to the Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Living_Torah_and_Nach) discussing them.

Comment: amazing series. I highly recommend

Answer (score 0):

Best? I'm not sure but I'm currently using Artscroll's "The Chumush, Stone Edition" and it's been very helpful in my learning. Gives an idea of how the Hebrews interpret the bible. The translation is slightly different due to the choice of words and it adds a lot of information for deeper research. I did not regret investing in this :) Highly recommend this if you're serious and want to dig more treasures from the Torah. Internet resources are very helpful too, just search the right thing and read from the right sources / articles.

Comment: I'm just disappointed how they translate Sheol as grave in every single instance

Answer (score 0):

I can put a word in for Robert Alter's edition ([link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hebrew-Bible-Translation-Commentary/dp/0393292495/ref=sr_1_1?adgrpid=64442265280&dchild=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwxev3BRBBEiwAiB_PWAd3OO4oldcu5n3SMItiEyc5pkY3jWAAqApgtPpiSp5XchfvEgSy5BoC7o4QAvD_BwE&hvadid=310639057370&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9045955&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=18150985407923931079&hvtargid=kwd-303055574137&hydadcr=11879_1790511&keywords=robert%20alter%20bible&qid=1593506979&sr=8-1&tag=googhydr-21)). Although it includes no Hebrew, it's a Jewish translation - and one of the first translations by a single individual rather than a committee - which preserves as much of the Hebrew poetry, wordplay and allusion as possible. There's also a short [companion volume](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Bible-Translation-Robert-Alter/dp/0691181497) on the translator's technique.