# What is the best translation of the Tanakh with commentary?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, commentaries, translation

I am looking for a good translation of the Tanakh with commentary.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include criteria that would qualify a translation and commentary as good.

Comment: best translation is very subjective. The way this question is asked would result in only opinionated answers with no clear empirical answer

Comment: relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/what-is-the-best-english-translation-of-the-tanakh-hard-copy-not-online and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8919/11501